Swagger UI doos not show Authenticate button in Spring Boot
I am using Swagger UI to test APIs for Spring Boot on Mac. However, the authenticate button does not show up so that I can put a JWT token for authentication. How can I solve this issue?
I searched the Internet and there are only solutions for .NET

Is the api generated from openapi or is is manually coded in spring boot? The answer will differ.

How are you generating your swagger-ui?  If you are generating from an openAPI schema (json or yml), please post schema.  If you are using something like springfox or springDoc, please post your relevant spring properties or annotations.  We can't fix your issue without knowing what you are doing.  Please take a look at the minimum, reproducible example post for an idea on how to form a good question.  Thanks.

APIs are coded manually in spring boot. I use springDoc for Swagger UI. I actually don't know where is the problem, so I can try something to fix it.

Here is the maven dependency I use in pom.xml file:

org.springdoc
springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui
2.0.2


If you are using swagger annotations add the following to you main spring boot class:
@OpenAPIDefinition(security = { @SecurityRequirement(name = "jwt"), @SecurityRequirement(name = "basic") })


Hi, I do not use swagger annotations, but I still used the line you provided. After using it the lock icons appeared on the apis, but nothing happens when I click on them.
